# Division with square root of x in counter

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, fractions

I'm trying to understand following equation:

$
\frac {\sqrt x + \sqrt{(x+1)}} {x-(x+1)} = -(\sqrt x + \sqrt{x+1})
$

Which steps do I need to take to get to the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because $$x-(x+1)=-1.$$ It's all!

Comment: Well ... I did not see that. I feel like an idiot ^^ Thank you

Comment: You are welcome!